# Error 2 Cannot implicitly convert type 'int' to 'SmallStore.Product_Type'

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework, relational-database

This is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SmallStore
{
    public partial class AddProduct : Form
    {
        private db_Entities db = new db_Entities();
        private Byte[] byteBLOBData;

        public AddProduct()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            comboCatagory.DataSource = db.Product_Type.ToList();
            comboCatagory.DisplayMember = "Description";
            comboCatagory.ValueMember = "Product_Type";
            comboCatagory.Invalidate();
        }

        private void AddProduct_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //check the data type cant cast to int dont know why
            //MessageBox.Show(comboCatagory.SelectedValue.GetType().ToString());
        }

        private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                FileStream fsBLOBFile = new       FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                byteBLOBData = new Byte[fsBLOBFile.Length];
                fsBLOBFile.Read(byteBLOBData, 0, byteBLOBData.Length);
                MemoryStream memBLOBData = new MemoryStream(byteBLOBData);
                pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(memBLOBData);
            }
        }

        private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Product product = new Product();
            product.Description = txtDescription.Text;
            product.Price = decimal.Parse(txtPrice.Text);
            product.Image = byteBLOBData;
            /*THIS IS THE PROBLEM*/
            product.Product_Type = (int)comboCatagory.SelectedValue; 
            db.Products.Add(product);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
}
```

i have been wracking my brain on this problem for 2 days now. i have a dbEntities model bound to a comboCatagory box in a Product SQL table. Product_type is of type int and description is a varchar(MAX). everything else is working. when i save "btnSave_Click" i get an invalid cast error. Can anyone please explain what i am doing wrong. i been using c# for a week i come from java and c/x86asm. im am very new to .net and entity framework. i know there are other ways to do this but i really like the EF. Thanks friends! also i did check other questions but they are not dealing with ef and data binding to combobox.

Comment: Do you have a field in Product called  product.Product_Type_Id? or something like that?

Comment: No this table 'Product_Type' has ProductType and Description. ProductType is a primary key. There is a product table which has ProductType also and it is related to the other ProductType in product table. ProductType on both tables are int.

Comment: public int ProductType { get; set; }
 public string Description { get; set; } this is in Product_Type.cs

Comment: I made a mistake when I uploaded this code.

Comment: Please check my new answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the problem, you need "ProductType" not "Product_Type" in value member of the Combobox

```
public AddProduct()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        comboCatagory.DataSource = db.Product_Type.ToList();
        comboCatagory.DisplayMember = "Description";
        comboCatagory.ValueMember = "ProductType"; //Not Product_Type
        comboCatagory.Invalidate();
    }
```

Comment: product.ProductType = (int)(comboCatagory.SelectedValue); is the problem. i get a invalid cast error.

Comment: @Soundview You mean the parenthesis? No, that's not a problem! in value member you where referencing Product_Type which is the class, and ProductType is the property!

Comment: I understand that comment now, yes, you are receiving that error in that row, but the cause of the error is the one in this answer, please make a test and let me know what happens

Comment: Thank you sir! I didnt get exception! Good Times!!!! *Happy Dance* did a query to my Product Table and every thing worked.

Comment: Since im a new user i cant publicly upvote. gotta answer some questions.

Comment: i just did. You answered so fast! I love this site.

Answer (score 0):

This is the code that compiles i made a error in the first one

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.ComponentModel;
 using System.Data;
 using System.Drawing;
 using System.IO;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Text;
 using System.Windows.Forms;

 namespace SmallStore
{
    public partial class AddProduct : Form
{
    private db_Entities db = new db_Entities();
    private Byte[] byteBLOBData;

    public AddProduct()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboCatagory.DataSource = db.Product_Type.ToList();
        comboCatagory.DisplayMember = "Product_Type";
        comboCatagory.ValueMember = "Description";
        comboCatagory.Invalidate();

    }

    private void AddProduct_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //check the data type cant cast to int dont know why
        //MessageBox.Show(db.Product_Type.ToList().GetType().ToString());
    }

    private void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            FileStream fsBLOBFile = new FileStream(openFileDialog1.FileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            byteBLOBData = new Byte[fsBLOBFile.Length];
            fsBLOBFile.Read(byteBLOBData, 0, byteBLOBData.Length);
            MemoryStream memBLOBData = new MemoryStream(byteBLOBData);
            pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromStream(memBLOBData);
        }
    }

    private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Product product = new Product();

        product.Description = txtDescription.Text;

        product.Price = decimal.Parse(txtPrice.Text);

        product.Image = byteBLOBData;

        /*this is the line in question*/

        product.ProductType = (int)(comboCatagory.SelectedValue);

        db.Products.Add(product);

        db.SaveChanges();

    }
}
```

}

Comment: If this is an update to your question, click on "edit" under your question, edit it in, and delete this answer. Please don't post this as an answer unless it is an answer. Otherwise, what is it doing here?